# SQL join incomplete table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

imagine I have two tables (see picture). In one I have dates, and in the other I have a count for some of the dates that are in the first one.

I need to join those tables so I have for each date in the table Dates the most updated count (up to that date).
For example, for the [Dates].[date]=3 I don't have a [Counts].[Count], so I have to take the count for [date]=1.

What is the best way of doing this in SQL?

I hope you can understand me :)

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: can you provide structure and sample data? perhaps on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: This can't be both mysql and sql server.  Which is it?

Comment: Looks trivial using a WINDOW function lead() plus an aggregate SUM() BTW: date is a reserved word (typename), and so is count (aggregate function) For mysql (which lacks WINDOW functions) you'd have to use a self-join using MAX() and/or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I think you have mistaken while showing your expected results, Since date 2 and 3 is not present in counts, the result should have 0

Comment: @SashiKant - that is exactly what the question is, this is not a simple left join.  run the fiddle in Joachim's answer and see it work.

Comment: @Hogan: Thanks for pointing it out, Have removed my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to do this; use an extra left join with a null check to make sure that there exists no newer matching date;

```
SELECT d.`date`, c.`count`
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN counts c  ON d.`date` >= c.`date`
LEFT JOIN counts c2 ON d.`date` >= c2.`date` AND c.`date`<c2.`date`
WHERE c2.`date` IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed32/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select d.date,
       (select c.count
        from counts c
        where d.date >= c.date
        order by c.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as count
from dates d;
```

This should even be relatively efficient, if you have an index on `counts(date, count)`.